# Chartjs show labels but not ticks

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS in my React application to render Bar chart with vertical bars and
I need to display the label at the bottom of each bar but hide the vertical lines that come in between bars (ticks). Here is what I tried so far:

**This does the opposite from what I want, it shows the ticks but not the labels:**

```
xAxes : [ {
        display : true, // set this to false to hide the labels under the bars
        ticks: {
            display : false
        }
    }]
```

**This shows everything:**

```
xAxes : [ {
            display : true, // set this to false to hide the labels under the bars
            maxTicksLimit: 0
        }]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the gridline display to false?

```
xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {display:false}
    }]
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/h109x67x/)

Answer (score 0):

For Chartjs 2.9.3, you can use:

```
    xAxes: [{
      gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false,
       }
    }]
```